# How can I set -X (X11Forwarding) in my ~/.ssh/config file for a specific host?

Tags: ssh, x11forwarding

So if I'm VPN'ing in from home, I want all of those connections to have `-X` specified. I already have the keys copied and an entry in `~/.config` with the ip and userid so all I have to do is go: `ssh wk` so this is the last fly in the ointment.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you peek into the manual page for [`ssh_config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), you will find an option `ForwardX11`, which can be put in your config such as:

```
Host wk
  Hostname W.X.Y.Z
  ForwardX11 yes
```

And then your connections to host `wk` will have X11 forwarding enabled by default.

Comment: Yup. Numbskull moment for me although in the past the settings were different in /etc/ssh/sshd_config than they were in ~/.ssh/config

Comment: they still are. `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` are different things with different options and different manual pages with description inside.

Comment: this is worth a read for anyone landing here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/security-concerns-with-x11-forwarding